# Gravar um cód na tarja magnética

Tags: c#, asp.net

Eu tenho uma impressora Evolis Dualys 3 que tem a opção de gravar um cód na tarja magnética do cartão, pelo software de terceiros a gravação foi realizada com sucesso, agora eu gostaria de fazer essa gravação pela minha aplicação, alguém já fez algo parecido?

Me enviaram um SDK do fabricante mas ao tentar executar o mesmo aparece o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tente mudar a configuração de ANYCPU para x86 nas configurações do projeto:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Era isso msm, vlw..